# Problems in restore backups to iPhone from PC

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

My dad wanted me to update his iPhone X to iOS 14, so I tried to, and iTunes in the PC gave some error about connecting to the iPhone (unfortunately I don't have the exact message error), so then I went to my Mac and updated his iPhone from there.

Now I can't restore his iPhone from backup (from the PC), due to "read and write" error. I have checked the access privilege to the backups folder and discovered it was empty!
iTunes says that the iPhone was backed up.
I would have checked if his iPhone was backed up on my Mac, but I went back to my apartment.

Any thoughts on how to restore from backup (or how to check if its a lost cause)?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, there's two different backup folders you may have, from older iTunes versions.

In the Windows 10 search box, paste in each of these locations separately and see if Backup isn't empty:

- %userprofile%\Apple\MobileSync\Backup
- %appdata%\Application Data\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup

Assuming you find the backup safe and sound in the other spot, the read or write error itself has several possible causes, but the one I'd start with: is the PC very low on disk space?

Comment: The backups are indeed in %userprofile%\Apple\MobileSync\Backup. The C: drive is very low on space, and every time we clear some space the iTunes backup restore fills it (its 128GB iPhone). I'm thinking about moving it to our E: drive which has plenty of space. Do you know if it would be possible just to copy the Apple folder to E: drive and then create shortcut in the C: drive where the original apple folder would have been?

Comment: Yes, you can reroute the backups to an external drive, but you'll have to create a junction from the location iTunes expects to your external drive folder. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112906/iphone-ipad-back-up-to-different-hard-drive/112940#112940 https://deciphertools.com/support/knowledge-base/decipher-textmessage-store-external-drive/ (Can I store iTunes backups on an external drive this same way?)